# Writing console lines to file

Tags: c#, console-application, streamwriter, console.writeline

I have a console app in c# and am trying to make it so that all the lines in the console are written into a file. I have tried using a streamwriter.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"location", true))
{
    writer.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

But using these methods the output text file was still empty. Am I missing something?

Solution: 
write this at the place where you want to start recording the text

```
        Console.Clear();
        StringWriter sw = null;
        sw = new StringWriter();
        Console.SetOut(sw);
```

write this at the end

```
    string s = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        File.WriteAllText(@"file location", s);
```

text wouldn't display on console if I do that but does not matter in this case.

Comment: Did you at least *try* to read the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx

Comment: I took your code and it worked fine for me. Typed text into the console and it outputed to the file. Console.ReadLine blocks until you press enter, I assume you understand that?

Comment: Works for me as well. What is the issue. You know you need to type in text then press enter and that will be returned with Console.ReadLine(). Also regarding your code with args, where is args been defined?

Answer (score 3):

```
StringWriter sw = null;
        try
        {
            sw = new StringWriter();
            Console.SetOut(sw);
            Console.Write("test");
            string s = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            File.WriteAllText("c:\\BACKUP\\temp.txt", s);
        }finally
        {
            if(sw != null)
            {
                sw.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need learn, how to use `Streams`, for after, work with the console output stream. You can see how to do it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out.aspx